# okhttp3 multipart отправить текстовое поле в кодировке utf-8

Tags: android, post, кодировка, okhttp

отправляю текст с андроида на http сервер таким образом:

```
MultipartBody.Builder builder=new MultipartBody.Builder()
                                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
builder.addFormDataPart("texttosend",readyText);  
RequestBody requestBody=builder.build();
CountingRequestBody countingRequestBody=new CountingRequestBody(requestBody,listener);
Request request=new Request.Builder()
    .url("http://"+ip+":"+port)
    .post(countingRequestBody)
    .build();
call = client.newCall(request);
call.enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {
        hnd.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                alert("Ошибка при загрузке: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
        hnd.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //........
            }
        });
    }
});
```

но русские символы не признает. как установить кодировку urf-8 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN =
      MediaType.parse("text/x-markdown; charset=utf-8");

Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(ANY_URL)
      .post(RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN, postBody))
      .build();
```

Comment: `Request request=new Request.Builder()
                                        .url("http://"+ip+":"+port)
                                        .post(RequestBody.create(textutf8,readyText))
                                        .build();`  отвечает "Multipart body must have at least one part"